# Excel File Download C# via POST(to avoid 404.15 query string error)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am currently working on an MVC project. I have a button which would generate a report in excel format.

I have gone through couple of previous questions asked by many other users.

Is there a way to pass the query string via POST to avoid query length.

this is what i see in the database error log.

NO USER 404.15 Not Found "/GD15/Batching/PaymentReport?
    checkIds=**67284%7C66283%7C66288%**..................

i pass somewhere around 200 checkId's to the controller via javascript to generate the excel file.
Any help is appreciated.

#Javascript file code snippet.(using knockout)

```
       self.onClickDownload = function () {
       if (!self.actionsEnabled()){
  return;
}

var selectedRows = self.paymentGrid.selectedRows();
var checkIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
  checkIds[i] = selectedRows[i].Id;
}

self.isDownloading(true);

$.fileDownload(gControllerName + "/PaymentReport", {
  data: { checkIds: checkIds.join("|") },
  successCallback: self.onDownloadComplete,
  failCallback: self.onDownloadFailed
});
```

}

## Controller (code snippet)

```
  public ActionResult PaymentReport(string checkIds)
  {
  Report report = new Report
  {
    ReportDataProvider = 
   "BKO.App.Reporting.ReportDataProviders.PaymentDataProvider",
    ReportFileFullName = "Payment.rdlc"
  };
  string mimeType;
  byte[] excelData = ReportGenerator.GetReportData(ReportFormatEnum.EXCEL, 
  report, "CheckNumberList=" + checkIds, out mimeType);
  Response.AppendCookie(new System.Web.HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true"));
  return File(excelData,"application/vnd.ms-excel","PaymentReport_"+".xls");
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use a post, maybe it's easier to put the data in the body of the request.

Comment: @Stefan:how do i do that with respect to the above JS. I dont know if i am doing something wrong here. Do i need a form tag(necessary?) to use POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$.fileDownload(gControllerName + "/PaymentReport", {
  data: { checkIds: checkIds.join("|") },
```

to:

```
$.fileDownload(gControllerName + "/PaymentReport", {
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  data: { checkIds: checkIds.join("|") },
```

to ensure that the data is sent through `POST` rather than `GET`.

Comment: Don't forget to change (if applicable) the `[HttpGet]` attribute to `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @JohnPavek : Thanks for the update have added the [HttpPost] to controller :)

Comment: mjwills: The solutions works like a charm, thanks :)